# Mootools addEvent with multiple id's

Tags: mootools

How can I use this function more times:

```
$('GotoHome').addEvent('click', function(event) {
    event = new Event(event).stop();
    scroll.toElement('middlerightwrapper');
});
```

If I create multiple links with the `ID="GotoHome"` it doesn't work anymore, only with one ID.
I don't want to duplicate like, GotoHome1, GotoHome2, GotoHome3

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest adding a common class to your elements and using the [dollars function](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Window%3adollars) to add the click hander:

**HTML**

```
<a href="" class="common-class" id="GotoHome1">Goto Home 1</a>
<a href="" class="common-class" id="GotoHome2">Goto Home 2</a>
<a href="" class="common-class" id="GotoHome3">Goto Home 3</a>
```

**Mootools**

```
$$('.common-class').addEvent('click', function(event) { 
    event = new Event(event).stop(); 
    scroll.toElement('middlerightwrapper'); 
});
```

The dollars function returns an array of all elements that match the selector.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have more than an element with a in (eg: id MUST be unique on your page), it is not a mootools issue or requirement, it is a html one (though browser forgive a lot loose programs).

You shoud rely on classes other than id

```
$$('.GotoHome').addEvent('click', function(event) { 
     event = new Event(event).stop(); scroll.toElement('middlerightwrapper'); }
);
```

or, if you have an enclosing container you can use event delegation to have a single entry point instead of multiple addEvent function:

```
 $('container-id').addEvent("click:relay(.GotoHome)", function(event) { 
     event = new Event(event).stop(); scroll.toElement('middlerightwrapper'); }
);
```

<strike>I'm not on my development workstation and can't check for the relay syntax in event manager, It will worth a check</strike>

**Edit**

[Hint on delegating events from mootools official site](http://mootools.net/blog/2011/03/28/events-with-mootools-element-class-delegation-and-pseudos/)